# Calculate cell/pixel area with Rasterio in Python

Tags: python, gdal, area, rasterio, pixel

**The Situation**

I have a tile spanning 10° north-south (n-s) and 10° east-west (e-w), e.g. from 10-20W and 10-20N. This tile contains multiple pixels, e.g. with a resolution of n-s and e-w of 100m at the equator (~0.0008°). This raster contains information of biomass in tons/hectare (for every pixel).

These 10x10° tiles span the whole world and are currently in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.

In the end, I would like the absolute biomass in every pixel, and therefore need to multiply the tons/hectare information with the corresponding pixel size.

I am currently using this [Determine area of cell in raster (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317392/determine-area-of-cell-in-raster-qgis) to create a new raster, and then do raster multiplication with the tons/hectare raster.

**The Question**

How can I calculate the area of every 100x100m pixel in **Rasterio**? I am looking for an approach that works world-wide. If possible also without creating a new raster, but rather multiplying the tons/hectare raster "inplace" with its pixel area.

I would already be happy if the current code I am using could be "translated" to Rasterio, as I am a bit confused between GDAL's raster.GetGeoTransform() and Rasterio's raster.transform.

Answer (score -1):

The correspondence  between GDAL's raster.GetGeoTransform() and Rasterio's raster.transform is easy (look at [Python affine transforms](http://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html) and [how to take cell size from raster using python or GDAL or RASTERIO](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243648/2581))

**Pixel size with rasterio**

```
import rasterio as rio
ww = rio.open("wgs84_raster.tif"
gt = ww.transform
gt
Affine(0.0004977676400361997, 0.0, 5.096854802788522,
   0.0, -0.00031309240744181374, 50.123699567610515)
# this is an affine matrix
print(gt)
| 0.00, 0.00, 5.10|
| 0.00,-0.00, 50.12|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
pixelSizeX = gt[0]
pixelSizeY =-gt[4]
print(pixelSizeX) # in degrees
0.0004977676400361997
print(pixelSizeY) # in degrees
0.00031309240744181374
```

The resulting area is in square degrees. If you want square kilometers, you need to reproject the raster

Convert the rasterio transform matrix to Gdal geotransform

```
 print(gt.transform.to_gdal())
 (5.096854802788522, 0.0004977676400361997, 0.0, 50.123699567610515, 0.0, -0.00031309240744181374)
```

**Pixel size with gdal**

```
from osgeo import gdal
raster= gdal.Open("wgs84_raster.tif")
got = raster.GetGeoTransform()
print(got) 
(5.096854802788522, 0.0004977676400361997, 0.0, 50.123699567610515, 0.0, -0.00031309240744181374)

pixelSizeX = got[1]
pixelSizeY =-got[5]
print(pixelSizeX) # in degrees
0.0004977676400361997
print(pixelSizeY) # in degrees
0.00031309240744181374
```

The resulting area is in square degrees

Convert gdal geotransform to rasterio transform matrix

```
af = rio.Affine.from_gdal(*got)
af
Affine(0.0004977676400361997, 0.0, 5.096854802788522,
   0.0, -0.00031309240744181374, 50.123699567610515)
```

You can also use directly the [affine](https://pypi.org/project/affine/) module (included in rasterio)

```
from affine import Affine
af = Affine.from_gdal(*got)
```

But the resulting area is in square degrees and not square meters