# Create raster with angles between single point and all raster pixels in QGIS

Tags: raster, point, pixel, angles

I would like to create a raster in which the cell values contain the angle between that cell and a single vector point. It would be as though a line were projected between the cell and the point, and the angle would be that between this line and a line-oriented to 0 degrees (straight north). I can’t find a function in ArcGIS or QGIS that might easily accomplish this.

It seems that what I’m asking for is the azimuth of raster cells relative to a single point. This old question was the same but wasn’t definitively answered: [Creating direction raster in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248047/creating-direction-raster-in-qgis)

Comment: I'm curious. Why?

Comment: It’s part of a visibility analysis for an elliptical structure. With that info I can solve the width of the structure from any angle.

Comment: @Matt what workflow did you come up with? I'm trying to do something similar to calculate widths between structures.

Answer (score 3):

You could rasterize your point then use the [Euclidean Direction Raster](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/euclidean-direction.htm) tool.  You will need a Spatial Analyst license for this tool in ArcGIS.  I also see that this tool is slated for deprecation and set to be replaced [with this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/distance-accumulation.htm).

Comment: This is the solution I used, however, it creates a raster with directions from the raster pixels to the point, rather than vice versa. I used the raster calculator to reorient the directions: Con(rastername >180, rastername - 180, rastername + 180)

Answer (score 3):

Using QGIS:

1. `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Raster pixels to points` to convert the raster to a point layer (one point for each pixel center)
2. Create a new attribute `azimuth` with Field Calculator and this expression:

   ```
   degrees(
       azimuth( 
           overlay_nearest(
               'point',  -- replace by name of your point layer
               $geometry
           )[0],
           $geometry
       )
   )
   ```
3. Menu Raster > Conversion > [Rasterize (vector to raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalrasterize) and set the attribute `azimuth` from step 2 as input for `Field to use for a burn-in value` parameter.

Result - azimuth from red point:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In *R* you can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=36,nrow=18, crs="+proj=merc")
 
point <- cbind(0, 0)
r <- rasterize(point, r, 1)
 
b <- direction(r, degrees=TRUE) 
plot(b)
```

[image]